# Meaning of comparator

Tags: meaning

> The FDA is increasing stakeholder communications related to biosimilars, including timely guidance for sponsors in order to provide scientific and regulatory predictability, as well as more efficient structures to support the development and review of biosimilar and interchangeable products. This includes efforts to harmonize international regulation of biosimilars and the acceptance of **non-U.S. comparator** products, as well as greater use of real-world data supporting regulatory decision making related to biosimilars.[FDA](https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm613761.pdf)

Hi, What is "non-U.S. comparator"?
I searched "comparatotr", and google says:

> a device for comparing a measurable property or thing with a reference or standard.[Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=comparator&gws_rd=ssl)

But still I have no idea.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something used as a standard for comparison: *even taking the most favourable comparator the company is about 20 per cent higher.*

Apple dictionary.

Someone is still trying to use the biggest words they can find rather than trying to make their information easy to read & comprehend. This is terrible writing style, even if there is nothing actually "wrong with it".
It's 'buzzword terminology' at its worst.

> This includes efforts to harmonize international regulation of biosimilars and the acceptance of non-U.S. comparator products

"non-U.S. comparator products" would be products not made in the US that could be used as reliable comparisons with US products.

Someone is trying to make it simpler to use, for instance, Tylenol [US] or Anadin [UK] as viable comparisons. Both are just paracetamol with a different brand name. ie, biosimilars.